# HTML how to make a clickable button on top of an image

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I want to make an web page with a image with an clickable link which directs to an another web page. I don't want that the full image is clickable, just a small part of it.

Maybe my question sounds stupid, but I'm new to HTML.
Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to make part of an image link somewhere, use an *image map*.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but where can i find an image map?

Comment: just google 'image map' and look through the tutorials.  Here is a common one, but you can probably find better ones http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: why did this get voted down when it is a.) correct, and b.) acknowledged by OP as the answer

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I suspect the reason was because you didn't provide enough information in your answer. That is, had you provided the example that you linked in your comment the answer would not have been downvoted. However, a correct answer is +15; a downvote only -1.

Answer (score 2):

Like @programminginallston said, you should use an image map.

To use an image map, add a `usemap` attribute to your `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="img/image.png" alt="an image" usemap="#usethismap">
```

Next, put a `<map>` tag in and add `<area>` tags to define clickable areas:

```
<map name="usethismap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" alt="Area Description" href="otherpage.html">
</map>
```

You can read more at MDN:

- [`map` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)
- [`area` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this, just for those who need another method, is to position another element (a button, a div, etc) overtop the image and make it clickable. For example, you can position an invisible div (css: `opacity:0;`) wherever you want and make it clickable.

I use jQuery to make the element (div) clickable, so you must then include a reference to the jQuery library in the `<head>` tags for that page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The secret is to put both the img and the clickable div inside another div. The outer div is position:relative, while the inner div is position:absolute.

```
#clickableDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top: 290px;
    left:85px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[See this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/twK2k/), where I have combined both the imagemap and the hidden div methods.